# Exception handling issue with java SecurityManager checkPermission(Permission perm)

Tags: java, security, exception

Why this doesn't yell to surround with try catch or throw from mathod?

```
import java.security.Permission;

public class NewSecurityManager extends SecurityManager{

    public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
        throw new SecurityException("You are drunk. Please go home!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh It is a Runtime exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SecurityManager extends `RuntimeException` which causes it to be an [unchecked exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html). 
Unchecked exceptions dont require enclosing `try/catch` blocks or the exception to be rethrown from the containing method.

Comment: Got it dude just after posted the question. :). Now I can't delete it.

Comment: @NamalFernando nw, it happens :)

Answer (score 3):

```
java.lang.Object
  java.lang.Throwable
      java.lang.Exception
          java.lang.RuntimeException
              java.lang.SecurityException
```

As you can see above SecurityException is the child of RuntimeException so you dont need any throw clause. Only checked exception are  forced to deal with , not unchecked(Runtime) ones

Comment: Thank you M Sach. Am I drunk and Do I need to go home? :)